# whats does assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, SRE module mismatch AssertionError: SRE module mismatch error mean?

Tags: python, django, anaconda

Hello I´m trying to run a `python manage.py runserver` command but getting this error message

> File "C:\Users\adrie\Anaconda3\lib\sre_compile.py", line 17, in 
>       assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
>   AssertionError: SRE module mismatch

Does anyone have idea of what´s happening here?

I had anaconda installed previously and was running fine. But then I´ve deinstalled and reinstalled anaconda, and I´m getting this error now.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you do not have any mismatch between Python interpreter version used (like 3.7) and the 're' python module (like 3.6.1).

Answer (score 2):

My `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables were pointing to the wrong version. By fixing this `import sre_compile` was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need reinstall IDLE or anaconda

Comment: that is the ONLY solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your installed python version matches exactly the version anaconda uses. If not get another python version. 
On Windows you can see the anaconda python version in control center -> uninstall programm -> Name of Anaconda.
Also make sure there are no older python version installed (that still might have environmental variables that point to them).

Answer (score 0):

You can switch your Python version of Anaconda. There should be no need to uninstall Anaconda.

Check for available Python versions:

```
conda search python
```

Choose your preferred Python version:

```
conda install python=3.7.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a permanent solution, more of a workaround.

I received the same error message when trying to use Miniconda3.
All conda commands were failing/resulting in this error.

After consulting with my team and comparing the contents of our "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Lib" directories, we realized that I was the only one that had a "re" module within that directory.

Deleting the "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Lib\re" module resolved this error.