# Pycharm, SRE module mismatch when creating new project after installing next interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

I've installed Python 3.7 next to 3.5 with windows installer downloaded from official site (I've added to PATH using this installer). When I try to create New Project with Virtualenv and Python 3.7 I get an error:
[image]
[image]

My System Variables:

PATH

```
C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DLLs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
```

I can't see anything with Python37-32 so I've tried o add it manually but the resoult was the same so I got back to old PATH.

My PATH:

```
C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DLLs;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib;C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
```

There is no PYTHONPATH in my variables. Is that a problem?
There is no much about this issue. The only thing I've found in the traceback is that it tries to use Python35-32 and I've no idea why.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600426/whats-does-assert-sre-magic-magic-sre-module-mismatch-assertionerror-sre-m

Comment: I know this topic. First answer says about checking mismatches between interpreters and I don't understand what the author means by that. Next is about Anaconda but I use Virtualenv not Anaconda. The last answer is about `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` and I don't have that variables. The next thing is that according to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30832 `PYTHONPATH` can cause that problem.

Comment: It means that somewhere two conflicting Python versions are set which probably happened during one of the installations. I would deinstall both and then follow a proper guide like [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53846889/860196). If you just need it to work, you can also just deinstall both and download Anaconda which makes the setup much easier.